# How to activate/deactivate bluetooth in .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I want to switch bluetooth on an android device on/off. But I can't find a way to do that.

I managed to request the users permission for bluetooth acces but it seems, like there is no controll for this setting.

So how can I do it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/DagucarIRacerXamarin/blob/master/Activities/MainActivity.cs#L69) a legacy Xamarin.Android application for college. But for android, the code should be relatively the same...

Comment: And [this guy](https://github.com/TimoKinnunen/MauiXAMLBluetoothLE) seems to have written a basic .NET maui app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [BluetoothAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#disable()) to do that.

First of all, please add the following code about permissions in the `\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"  android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

And then add the following code in the `\Platforms\Android\MainActivity.cs`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt > Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.R && ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.BluetoothConnect) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.BluetoothConnect }, 102);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt <= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.R && ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Bluetooth) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.Bluetooth }, 102);

        }
    }
```

And then turn on/off in the page:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if ANDROID
       
        var bluetoothManager = (Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.BluetoothService);
        var bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.Adapter;
        if(bluetoothAdapter.IsEnabled == true )
        {
            bluetoothAdapter.Disable();
        }
        else
        {
            bluetoothAdapter.Enable();
        }
#endif

    }
```

**Note:** The `bluetoothAdapter.Disable();` and `bluetoothAdapter.Enable();` was deprecated in API level 33. And it can't work on the emulator api 33 but worked on the physical xiaomi device I tested which android version is api 33. It's strange.

**Update:**

You can use the following code after requesting the permission and it work on all the android versions:

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if ANDROID
        var enable = new Android.Content.Intent(
                    Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.ActionRequestEnable);
        enable.SetFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        var disable = new Android.Content.Intent(
                    Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.ActionRequestDiscoverable);
        disable.SetFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.NewTask);

          var bluetoothManager = (Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.BluetoothService);
          var bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.Adapter;
          if(bluetoothAdapter.IsEnabled == true )
          {
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(disable);
            //  disable the bluetooth;
        }
        else
          {
            // enable the bluetooth
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(enable);

        }
#endif

    }
```

Comment: This is not strange if the application fulfils one of the deprecation exceptions (Device Owner (DO), Profile Owner (PO) and/or system apps)

Comment: ... or Xiaomi has changed the behaviour of stock Android accordingly.

Comment: You are right and I have updated the answer and found the solution worked on all the android versions.  @Risto